# How to profile a program that doesn't wait for user input to run and exits quickly

Tags: java, profiling, visualvm

When profiling, with a tool such as VisualMV, what order should programs be run in? The program I want to profile runs relatively quickly and doesn't wait for the user to close it. It's not as if I can really quickly start the program, switch to the VisualVM and start the profiling process without the program terminating first.

What I've done is put in an extra line of code in my program that prompts the user to press enter to start. So I launch my program and when it says "press enter" I go to VisualVM, find the right process, go to the profiling tab and click CPU. Once VisualVM has finished setting up then I go back to my program and press enter to start it. Is this right? Or should it be done in a different order?

Obviously profiling only works on the portion of the program running at the time, right?

Comment: Out of curiosity, if this application runs and exists so quickly, traditional profiling steps are not applicable, what is it you hope to fix?

Comment: how are traditional profiling steps not applicable?

Comment: What I mean is that normally, you profile an application at runtime because of some performance issue, or as a preventative measure to detect memory leaks, or inefficient threads and the like... but in your case, the code seemingly executes quickly, and closes without issue. Given that, what is it you hope to learn / what is the problem you're trying to fix?

Comment: I have 3 alternative ways of implementing the same method, so that's what I'm testing (in a separate project).

Comment: The http://visualvm.java.net/eclipse-launcher.html is an Eclipse plugin for starting the jVisualVM together with the application, but it does not solve the issue of short-running programs. The "Startup Profiler" suggested by Tomas Hurka seems more appropriate here (+1, maybe I can now remove the `for (1..10) { sleep(1000); }` loops that I occasionally inserted to have enough time for setting up the jVisualVM config after startup...)

Comment: Can you put a top-level loop in your program, so whatever it's supposed to do, it does it 1000 times? That won't change the percents seen by the profiler.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin called [Startup Profiler](https://visualvm.github.io/startupprofiler.html) for VisualVM 1.3.6 or newer. It allows you to profile your application from the beginning.

Comment: VisualVM does not seem to be a very good program. This plugin works, however if I put a top level loop in to iterate over the entire program, it only crashes when VisualVM is running.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about VisualMV, but in JProfiler you can specify parameters which will force the program to wait until JProfiler connects. This way, no portion of the program is run before JProfiler is up and running profiling.

Comment: How and where do you specify these parameters, in the source code or in the profiler itself?

Comment: I think JProfiler agent will force JVM to wait for JProfiler UI to connect. There's a parameter to override this behavior so JVM starts even if JProfiler is not connected. E.g. this JVM param would start your app even without JProfiler: -agentpath:C:\PROGRA~1\JPROFI~1\bin\windows\jprofilerti.dll=port=8849,nowait. Note the nowait flag. So, it's not the source code and it's not the profiler, it's in the arguments for the profiler agent that controls JVM being profiled.